# Segue not working in Tabbed App with TableView and Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I've just read and watched about 20 videos, StackOverFlow questions and articles but they're all outdated.
[This tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/) and [video](http://vimeo.com/53563148) were the most helpful. You can see I followed the steps, but nothing happens when I click a cell.

I also overwrite didSelectRowAtIndexPath with some actions, and that executes properly when I click a cell, but the segue doesn't do anything.

I'm trying to setup my app so users look at the 2 tabs (each containing TableView) and can click on a cell to be sent to another screen. Similar to the interface of Twitter... tabs, and click on a TableView cell to view individual information.

When I used the Editor > Embed In feature of Xcode, it placed the Navigation Controller before the Table View. However, previously, I've been trying to: `TabView -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController`. I'm not sure who is right here. I tried both, and both didn't cause the view to change when I clicked a cell.

This should be able to be done without code, right?

1st attempt: Below I've done the first tab using the Editor > Embed In feature.

[image]

Another different approach/attempt: Below I've dragged in a navigation controller (which brought 2 boxes, one being a TableView for some reason) and setup a segue from the original TableView to the navigation controller.

[image]

Comment: The first attempt looks good. If you wish upload the project and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Sure, how should I do that?

Comment: on http://ge.tt/ or similar.

Comment: Your second attempt is not what you want. In your first attempt, when you setup the segue from the `UITableViewCell` to the `UIViewController`, which type of segue did you select? Also, did you control-drag from the table cell or from the table view controller's icon?

Comment: I chose `show` and I dragged from the cell on the story board a number of different times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two parts missing in your project:

1. The identifier for the segue on the Main.storyboard. I named it *details*.
2. `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("details", sender: self)` in the *tableView delegate* **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**.

Happy xCoding.

Comment: I just tested on a new project and I confirm that segues work without additional code. There must be something specific to your project that cause that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think either you have to do a manual segue, give an identifier to it and then call that segue by

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("myIdentifier", sender:self)
```

in your

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

or you do your segue in your storyboard by holding "ctrl" and then drag from your cell to the view Controller you want to go to. When you have NavigationController in front of your second ViewController, you have to drag to the NavigationController.

Actually this should work, I've used both of these quite a lot of times so far and I never had problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to comment, but i do not have enough reputation.

in addition to what @minneostasteve said, your storyboard is actually correctly set up in the first pic but not in the second pic

ie. tab bar controller -> navi controller -> tableviewcontroller -> viewcontroller

Comment: I overwrite didSelectRowAtIndexPath, is this the problem?

Comment: How do you mean? Does it give you an error? Are there even any data in the tableView? AFAIK, you'd actually need to define at least the datasource for table in your ViewController so that at least one cell is rendered/populated. Otherwise, you can never really push the 'detail view controller'

Comment: There is no error. Yes, the data is populated. The cell just turns blue once clicked.

Comment: if i were you, i'd open a new project with the master detail template and compare the code.

from your description, it seems like 

a) you have not set the tableview delegate to the VC,
b) you have not connected the Cell to the segue